# Join two files in a batch mode

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have many files with the following names:

```
      0001mm.xyz  , 0002mm.xyz , 0003mm.xyz ...
      0001qm.xyz  , 0002qm.xyz , 0003qm.xyz ...
```

I want to join the contents of `0001mm.xyz` and `0001qm.xyz` to produce a `0001.xyz` ; `0002mm.xyz` and `0002qm.xyz` to produce a `0002.xyz`, and so on.

Comment: Useful use of `cat`?

Answer (score 1):

To join two files, use [`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat).

```
cat 0001mm.xyz 0001qm.xyz >0001mm.xyz
```

To iterate over the input files, use a [for loop](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for). Loop over one of the input files, using a [wildcard pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```
for x in *mm.xyz; do … done
```

Given a file `$x` ending with `mm.xyz`, to get the name of the other input file and the name of the output file, use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) constructs to extract the stem.

```
for x in *mm.xyz; do
  stem="${x%mm.xyz}"
  cat "$x" "${stem}qm.xyz" >"${stem}.xyz"
done
```

Comment: I used your final script but an error happened,  it not found the qm.xyz file

Comment: @AlvaroLopez I'd made a mistake that Archemar fixed (thanks Archemar), see the edited answer.